# Error en consumo SOAP WS-Security: org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException Element ns1:

Tags: java, soap

Estoy realizando en Java el consumo de un WebService con WS-Security. Estoy usando Axis-1.6.2 y generé el stub con el Eclipse. Esta es la URL del servicio: https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6475/efactura/ws_personaGetActEmpresarial?wsdl

Este es el error que me genera:

```
       org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error in signature with X509Token
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:76)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:427)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:406)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
        at dgi_modernizacion_consolidado.WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarialStub.execute(WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarialStub.java:188)
        at uy.gub.dgi.gx.DGIEfactura.executeExecute(DGIEfactura.java:368)
        at uy.gub.dgi.gx.DGIEfactura.ExecuteDGIWS(DGIEfactura.java:197)
        at uy.gub.dgi.gx.DGIEfactura.EXECUTE(DGIEfactura.java:171)
        at Executor.main(Executor.java:29)
    Caused by: org.apache.rampart.RampartException: Error in signature with X509Token
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:741)
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:414)
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.build(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:90)
        at org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:147)
        at org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
        ... 12 more
    Caused by: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityException: Signature creation failed
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:721)
        at org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:732)
        ... 16 more
    Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
    Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.signature.ReferenceNotInitializedException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
    Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
    Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.transforms.TransformationException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
    Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
    Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
    Original Exception was org.apache.xml.security.c14n.CanonicalizationException: Element ns1:WS_PersonaGetActEmpresarial.Execute has a relative namespace: ns1="DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado"
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.calculateDigest(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Reference.generateDigestValue(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.Manifest.generateDigestValues(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.sign(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.ws.security.message.WSSecSignature.computeSignature(WSSecSignature.java:717)
        ... 17 more

    AxisFault -Error in signature with X509Token - Error in signature with X509Token -
```

Dentro del método execute del stub, está este código generado:

```
toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()), wS_PersonaGetActEmpresarialExecute0, optimizeContent(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado", "execute")), new javax.xml.namespace.QName("DGI_Modernizacion_Consolidado", "execute")); _serviceClient.addHeadersToEnvelope(env); _messageContext.setEnvelope(env); _operationClient.addMessageContext(_messageContext); _operationClient.execute(true);
```

En el .execute es donde cae la ejecución, si yo modifico los parámetros del `toEnvelope` a: `toEnvelope(getFactory(_operationClient.getOptions().getSoapVersionURI()))` 
logro pasar este error pero termina cayendo igual.